# 2d java minecraft game colliding with blocks

Tags: java

I'm making a 2D Minecraft-like platformer game which includes a player moving across blocks, but the player/block collision isn't working.
pretty much what im trying to do is collide with blocks that are 20 y 20 I have an array list of
 blocks :

public blocks block[][] = new blocks[50][50]

how do I collide with each individual block.

Please see the `Player` class below. If you would like to see the `Block` class, please let me know in the comments.

```
public class Player 
{
    public int x = 200;
    public int y = 10;
    public static int dir = 1;
    public static int fallingSpeed = 4;
    public static boolean col = false;
    public Image img, img1;

    public void tick()
    {           
        collide();

        if(col == false)
        {   
            y += fallingspeed;
            Comp.sy += fallingspeed;
        }
    }

    public void collide()
    {           
        if (x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x >= Comp.level.block.length  
            && y >= Comp.level.block[0].length - 21)
            col = true;
        else
            col = false;        
    }

    public void render(Graphics g)
    {
        if(dir == 1)
        {
            ImageIcon i2 = new ImageIcon("res/player2.png");
            img = i2.getImage();
            g.drawImage(img, x - Comp.sx, y - Comp.sy, null);
        }
        else if (dir == 2)
        {
            ImageIcon i2 = new ImageIcon("res/player1.png");
            img = i2.getImage();
            g.drawImage(img, x - Comp.sx, y - Comp.sy, null);               
        }           
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Please use code formatting for code, input/output & structured documents like HTML or XML.  To do that, select the sample and click the `{}` button above the messaged posting/editing form. 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 3) Please add an upper case letter at the start of sentences.  Also use a capital for the word I, and abbreviations and acronyms like JEE or WAR.  This makes it easier for people to understand and help.

Comment: First, I didn't get what you need help with, second, provide us with the code, you think is not actually working as you want it to be. And finally, as mentioned by @AndrewThompson please provide SSCCE for quick help and better responses. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we kinda need the Block class to make an example.

The basic idea is that you use a for loop to iterate thought every block and check if the player collides with it. You can use the Rectangle2D and Area classes to help detect the actual collision, by casting a Rectange2D object to a Area Object and using area1.intersects(area2).